# How to use gitlab CI environment variables in fastlane fastfile?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane

I am currently using a `.env` file to get environment variables in FASTFILE, but now I am trying to automate the fastlane using GitLab CI/CD.

Since the `.env` file which has all the keys can not be pushed to the branch I have to declare all the `.env` or the environment variables in the GitLab runner's environment variable.

I want to know how can I use the GitLab runners's environment variable in my fastfile.

```
 lane :build_staging do |options|
    environment_variable(set: { 'ENVFILE' => '.env.staging' }) // I want to use the GitLab environment variable
    clean
    gradle(task: options[:task], build_type: 'Staging', project_dir: 'android/')

  end
```

Comment: Hi, do you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html) site. It has some variables that start with `CI_`.
Once you find the one you are looking for, you can use `ENV['CI_COMMIT_TITLE']` in your Fastfile

Answer (score -2):

In `Settings` > `Variables`, you can define the whole file as a variable with a specified scope :

[image]

In your gitlab-ci, you would use it by specifying the variable name (in my example `$ENV_FILE`) and the scope using `stage` keyword in your job :

```
build:
  stage: staging
  script:
    # do your work here
```

You can find more info in the documentation for variable [file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#file-type) type and [scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html#scoping-environments-with-specs).